# SQL - Comparing consecutive records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called `schedules` that I'm using to manage locations of NPCs in a game, laid out like this example;

```
NPC    Location      Activity   Time
-------------------------------------
1      Village       Roaming    1000
2      Forest        Hunting    1100
3      Mill          Working    1000
1      Castle        ENTER      1100
1      Castle        Roaming    1100
1      Castle        Working    1200
```

Looking at this, NPC 1 roams villge at 10am, enters and roams the castle at 11am, then works at the castle at 12pm.

On the map load, I run a SQL statement to grab a list of times that an NPC will spawn at your current location;

```
SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE Activity='ENTER' AND Location='my location'
```

However I wondered if it was possible to clean the database by removing all the `ENTER` entries and just run a statement comparing the `Location` between consecutive `Time` records to see when an NPC enters instead.

Do I just need to loop through every entry for each NPC and compare current and previous locations, flagging ones that vary?

Comment: What does this mean:  " grab a list of times that an NPC will spawn at your current location"?  How is "spawning" related to your data?  What results do you want?  How will you know that an NPC "enters" if you don't have an "enter" annotation?

Comment: I was wondering if I could work out the 'ENTER' annotation instead by comparing each consecutive `Location` for each NPC (based on `Time`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do what you want.  In the most recent versions of MySQL, you would use `lag()`.  Earlier versions would require something like a correlated subquery.

However, I don't recommend it.  Your application cares about "ENTER".  Storing this fact directly in the data is the most efficient way to get this information.  You might have reasons for not including it (these reasons are not mentioned in the question).  From the perspective of simple performance, the trade-off of a few extra rows in the table for clarify of code and simplicity of queries is probably worth it.

Comment: Thanks. I have hundreds of ENTER entries but if it keeps the SQL simple I'll keep it

Answer (score 1):

Window functions (Available in Sqlite 3.25 and newer) are your friend:

```
CREATE TABLE npcs(id INTEGER, location TEXT, state TEXT, time INTEGER);
INSERT INTO npcs VALUES(1,'Village','Roaming',1000);
INSERT INTO npcs VALUES(2,'Forest','Hunting',1100);
INSERT INTO npcs VALUES(3,'Mill','Working',1000);
INSERT INTO npcs VALUES(1,'Castle','ENTER',1100);
INSERT INTO npcs VALUES(1,'Castle','Roaming',1100);
INSERT INTO npcs VALUES(1,'Castle','Working',1200);
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, location
           , lag(location, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS prev_location
           , state, time
      FROM npcs)
WHERE location != prev_location
ORDER BY id, time;
```

produces

```
id          location    prev_location  state       time      
----------  ----------  -------------  ----------  ----------
1           Castle      Village        ENTER       1100
```